# hibernate.cfg.xml not found error while running the application from JAR file

Tags: java, hibernate, jar, properties-file

I have exported my project into a JAR file. I have the ***hibernate.cfg.xml***  file inside the JAR and I have created ***hibernate.properties***  file, to change the hibernate settings without editing the ***hibernate.cfg.xml*** file directly. but by running the JAR file I'm getting below exception expecting ***hibernate.cfg.xml***  file to be there out side of the JAR file. But I want only the ***hibernate.properties***  file to be outside of JAR file to supply database settings.

Exception in console:

```
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibern
ate.cfg.xml not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at DataLayer.HibernateAdapter.buildSessionFactory(HibernateAdapter.java:
37)
        at DataLayer.HibernateAdapter.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:13)
        at DataLayer.ApplicationDbContext.<init>(DatabaseContext.java:10)
        at ScanningServer.MainProg.init(TestMain.java:58)
        at ScanningServer.MainProg.main(TestMain.java:25)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
        at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHe
lper.java:173)
```

buildSessionFactory():

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        Properties hib = new Properties();
        if (sessionFactory == null){
            try {
                hibernateProperties.load(HibernateUtil.class.getClassLoader().getSystemClassLoader()
                                                          .getResourceAsStream("hibernate.properties"));
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
                serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
                sessionFactory = configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Account.class)
                        .addAnnotatedClass(Consumer.class).addAnnotatedClass(Order.class)
                        .addAnnotatedClass(Customer.class)
                        .addAnnotatedClass(Products.class)
                        .addAnnotatedClass(Category.class)
                        .addAnnotatedClass(Schedules.class)
                        .addAnnotatedClass(Alert.class)
                        .mergeProperties(hibernateProperties)
                        .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + e);
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
            }
        }   
        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

hibernate.properties:

```
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/MyProjectDB?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.username=root
hibernate.connection.password=Admin123!
```

Please help me to overcome this!!

Comment: if the jar is in your classpath you can use the package/file location like that: `configure(“com/bla/hibernate.cfg.xml”)` that should works

Comment: @Paizo: jar file is in the resources folder. while running the project in Eclipse it is running fine. but I'm facing the problem only by running the exported jar file along with 'hibernate.properties' file outside of the jar file

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
URL input = HibernateUtil.class.getResource("hibernate.cfg.xml");  
configure(input).buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

Sorry try this

```
public class HibernateUtil {    

 private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

 private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
     try {                       
         ClassLoader classLoader = HibernateUtil.class.getClassLoader();             
         File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("Hibernate.properties").getFile());                                           
         Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();          
         hibernateProperties.load(new FileInputStream(file));                                           
         Configuration configuration = new Configuration();          
         configuration.configure("/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");            
         configuration.addProperties(hibernateProperties);           
         configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);                               
         StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());             
         SessionFactory sf = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
         return sf;          
     } catch (Throwable ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
         System.err.println("SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
         throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
     }
 }

 public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
     return sessionFactory;
 }

 public static void shutdown() {
     // Close caches and connection pools
     getSessionFactory().close();
 }
```

}

1. I created a maven project with hibernate depencies.
2. Export the project as  runnable jar file and check "package required libraries into generated jar"
3. Run with "java -jar myjar.jar"

Comment: I tried the same and got the below exception:

'INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Apr 13, 2015 11:12:19 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Apr 13, 2015 11:12:19 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000044: Configuring from URL: null
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError'